# Multiline Textview

Tags: android, textview, multiline

I Have one **TextView**, the text is too long can't fit in one line, How can I make this as multiline TextView? I have added `android:singleline="false"` attribute but it's not working.

```
<TextView
    android:text="some long text"
    android:singleline="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
/>
```

Comment: Please post some code or give more information so we can help you more.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya  I have added code pls check

Comment: If possible please post your full xml so i can test here before post my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give false the singleLine

Just give the

```
android:maxLine="Here define the line max as you want"
```

this will allow your text to add the number of line in width and height you defined in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:minLines="3"` for the `textview`

Comment: am using Textview not EditText

Answer (score 0):

After testing on  my emulator i come here..so do this

```
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
    t.setText("This is first line \n This is second  \n last line....");
```

Comment: still any confusion? feel free to ask..:):)

Answer (score 0):

Give

```
android:maxLine="Define max line here"
```

Answer (score 0):

You write in xml file for textview

android:maxLine="Define max line here"